# Salesforce Administrator can't see deployed flow from setup but can see from IDE

Tags: salesforcedx, visual-workflow, deployment, visibility

I deployed the whole project using SFDX from a repository and I can view my flow in my IDE but I can't see that flow from setup as a System Administrator - despite that I can see other flows - what can be the reason of this?

What permissions and settings should I check to fix that issue?

Comment: when you deployed, did package.xml include the new flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: the flow file was deployed as a process builder